# eliminar config file en runtime

Tags: json, asp.net, configuración

Este es mi problema:

Tengo un proyecto en .NET core 3.1, que es un servidor, una api. Usa appsettings.json, hasta ahí todo bien.

Complicación, tengo en la misma solución, otro proyecto, para testear mi api. El caso es que tengo dos batallas de tests distintos, una que 'da bien', es decir resultados ok200, y otra que se supone que debe ser de errores, respuestas 404, entre otras.

En mi api tengo appsettings.json, y el caso es que desde los tests (conecto al servicio) quiero eliminar appsettings.json y sustituirlo por otro archivo (appsettings2.json, appsettings3.json ...), pregunta, como elimino appsettings.json de la configuración? El tema es no tocar la api, por eso, las entradas del archivo de configuracion se han de recoger de la misma manera.

Ahora mismo el error está en esta linea:
`....SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Sources.Remove("appsettings.json")...` porque Remove necesita un IConfigurationSource y paso un string, como saco el IConfigurationSource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Sources` es de tipo `IList<IConfigurationSource>`.

Si quiere sacar todos los contenidos de este Sources, hace `SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Sources.Clear()`